# "super" keyword in class method

Tags: inheritance, smalltalk, class-method

I'm learning a basics of Smalltalk. There's a `super` keyword which is used to call a method from superclass inside a subclass method:

```
Object subclass: # A
   test
      ^1

A subclass: # B
   test
      ^2
   callSuper
      ^super test
```

So `B new callSuper` evaluates to `1`.

OK. That's clear.

So now, I'm defining a bunch of class methods for `B` class:

```
createNew1
    ^super new
createNew2
    ^self new
create
    ^self
createSuper
    ^super
```

And they evaluates respectively to `a B`, `a B`, `B` and an error (which shows me that `super` is not a cast to subclass but kind of a message dispatcher).

Why am I getting instances of `B` class despite `super` keyword? And what's a difference between `a B` and `B` objects? I've started to think that the `B` object is a special, singletone instance (just like `static` attributes are implemented in other languages) of class `B`, but still - I've checked and it's class is a `B` and subclass is an `A`.

**What is the semantics of `super` keyword in class methods?** How it differs from semantics inside objects methods? What really is the object which can be obtained by calling `self` inside class method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to answer this by myself despite that all the other answers are technically correct. That's because I was knowing about metaclasses and it seems that I have a proper semantics of `super` in my head, yet I was still getting unexpected results.

Turns out that **I've misunderstood the basis of inheritance** in Smalltalk and how methods are called.

I was thinking that for such code ...

```
Object subclass: #A
    test
        ^'A'
    getTest
        ^self test

A subclass: # B
    test
        ^'B'
    runTest
        ^super getTest
```

... the expression `B new runTest` is evaluated to `'A'` - that means, the method from the superclass is evaluated in upcasted object.

**But it isn't.**

It's evaluated to `'B'`, because there's no upcasting and when we're calling any method inside a superclass method - the search starts in the real class of the object, not class from which evaluated method comes.

As a result, calling `^self new` and `^super new`, while not defining a `new` in any of the classess, have the same effect - since both of them ends up with calling *Behaviour's* `new` implementation in the context of `self`.

Comment: If you're familiar with C#, everything makes sense if you consider every Smalltalk method (instance or class) as being declared as virtual.

Comment: "The expression B new runTest is evaluated to 'A'" No! Are you actually evaluating this code, or just doing a thought experiment?! One of the great benefits of Smalltalk is how easy it is to do experiments. If you evaluate "B new runTest", you'll see that it returns 'B'

Comment: @SeanDeNigris Maybe it's unclear due to my poor english, but I wanted to write, that I was thinking that it's evaluated to 'A' while in fact it's evaluated to 'B' (which is written in next paragraph). I'll try to edit this and make it clear.

Comment: @FrancescoBaruchelli I'm much more familiar with pure C++. But I've just tested it and it looks like virtual methods in C++ works in the same manner. Which was unexpected for me at first - but the more I'm thinking about it the less I know why I had the opposite intuition.

Answer (score 4):

`self` and `super` always refer to the same object, the current receiver. The only difference is that `self` starts the lookup of the following method send in the class of the receiver and `super` in the superclass of where the method is defined.

See Chapter 5 of [Pharo by Example](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/25599/PBE1-2009-10-28.pdf) for details.

Comment: But `new` is defined in `A`, so why `^super new` isn't returning `an A` object since it's called inside an object of a `B` class? Or maybe I just don't fully realize what is semantics of `new`?

Answer (score 4):

Your answer to the first example is wrong. `B new callSuper` returns 1. Lukas gave you the exact definition of the semantics of super. It's basically an alias for 'self' which modifies the method lookup for the message sent to it. `self message` will start looking for methods in the class of the receiver, `super message` will start searching in the superclass of the class  defining the method that contains the `super message` expression (so the class of the receiver isn't relevant in this case).

In your second example `super new` and `self new` end up calling the same method (defined somewhere in the Behavior hierarchy) because that's the closest method definition of new in both cases. If, however, you renamed the createNew methods to new, then `new ^self new` would be an infinite loop, whereas `new ^super new` calls the Behavior method.

Comment: Oh. That was a typo - I was having a `1` in head during asking. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

self and super mean the same thing whether in a class or an object, because a class *is* an object...

#createNew1 & #createNew2 are equivalent. As Lukas explained, super merely means "start method lookup in my superclass instead of my class". Since you haven't defined #new in either A or B, you will go looking up through the superclasses, eventually finding Behavior>>#new whether you start in A or B. #new starts by calling #basicNew, which creates and returns a new instance of B (i.e. "a B").

In #create & #createSuper, since you're not looking anything up, self and super are again equivalent and mean "return the current object" (what error were you referring to for the latter?). Now this part is confusing. Since everything in Smalltalk is an object, this includes classes themselves. So in this context, "the current object" is B, which is the only instance of the metaclass "B class". If you're really interested in understanding, I would read Chapter 13 of [Pharo By Example](http://gforge.inria.fr/frs/download.php/25599/PBE1-2009-10-28.pdf) over and over until it makes sense (I still haven't hit that point, lol).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I think you understood now...
When you send ^super new from B class, you still send the message to B class, it's just that the message is (super new)...
So you create an instance of B
Unless of course if you would define

```
A class>>new
    ^A basicNew
```